How to find lombok issue? Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile
I found many similar problems but none helps. I am trying to build and deploy a large project,I got error
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile

later trace points to many
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:485)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:285)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:1)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:394)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:292)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:531)

version
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.7
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.12-oracle-x64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8

how to find the root cause?

Update your lombok version to latest, compile parts until you have the file that causes this, file a bug.
